# Connection Time of Windows Ethernet Link in Powershell

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell

In the old-world "adapter properties" screen of Windows 10 there is a Status command which shows the traffic on the (Ether)Net adapter and how long the link is up. I need this time information in a Powershell script, has anybody an idea how to get that?

Unlike the adapter creation, install or reset time the timestamp or duration should mark when the last time a positive link state was reached (to see the last time a physical network unplug was healed).

I did not see it in `Get-NetAdapter` nor `netsh` nor `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapter`

[image: Screenshot Adapter Status]

Comment: This is just a tip aside of the answer, given a good one has already been given. If you output a command to `fl`, you will see its general properties, but not everything. If you output to `fl *` you see a whole lot more. So `get-netadapter | fl *` gives so much more than just `get-netadapter`. Same for the other commands.

Comment: I know that’s why I listed the commands which I checked and they seem to not have the property I need. I normally use `fc -depth 2 -property *`

Comment: Oh, that is a neat one. I have to remember that one. :) Thanks. `fc -depth 2 *` seems to work too. :) neat.

Comment: I would expect it to be this: `(Get-NetAdapter).TimeOfLastStateChange` but that returns empty. Also, can't find it in get-netadapterstatistics either. Ok, I dunno on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead the
[Get-CimInstance command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.1).

An example for getting the up-time is the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_networkadapter | where {$_.NetEnabled -eq $true} | select Name, @{N="Uptime"; E={(Get-Date) - $_.TimeOfLastReset}} |sort Name | fl
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, will try it. However in the WMI list (looks pretty similar to the CIM Instance) the TimeOfLastReset was the Boot time for me not the last re-connect time. I added some clarification to the Q.

Comment: @eckes works for me. Produces `Name   : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Uptime : 9.17:19:49.2187804` on my end.

Comment: @LPChip it gives a time, but is it the boot time or the time you unplugged the cable?

Comment: @eckes hmm, it seems time of last reboot. Does not appear to be the same as the time in the status window.

Comment: I suspect there is somewhere a different statistics object which may hold that time, would at least be required for SNMP, but haven’t found it yet

Comment: It might also be possible to use the eventlog for this. I'm sure the eventlog will write an entry when the connection comes online.